# DB Design: Looking for Performance improvement with a Column used in all SQL Queries

Tags: sql-server, database-design, normalization, performance, performance-tuning

I recently got added to a new ASP .NET Project(A web application) .There were recent performance issues with the application, and I am in a team with their current task to Optimize some slow running stored procedures.

The database designed is highly **normalized**. In all the tables we have a `BIT column` as `[Status_ID]`. In every `Stored procedures`, For every `tsql query`, this column is involved in `WHERE` condition for all tables.

```
Example:

Select      A.Col1,
            C.Info
From        dbo.table1 A
Join        dbo.table2 B On A.id = B.id
Left Join   dbo.table21 C On C.map = B.Map
Where       A.[Status_ID] = 1
And         B.[Status_ID] = 1
And         C.[Status_ID] = 1
And         A.link > 50
```

In the above `sql`, 3 tables are involved, `[Status_ID]` column from all 3 tables are involved in the `WHERE` condition. This is just an example. Like this `[Status_ID]` is involved in almost all the queries.

When I see the execution plan of most of the `SPs`, there are lot of **Key lookup (Clustered)** task involved and most of them are looking for [Status_ID] in the respective table.

In the Application, I found that, it is not possible to avoid these column checking from queries. So

Will it be a good idea to

1. Alter all `[Status_ID]` columns to `NOT NULL`, and then adding them to `PRIMARY KEY` of that table.
2. Adding `[Status_ID]` column to all the NON Clustered indexes in the `INCLUDE PART` for that table.

Please share you suggestions over the above two points as well as any other.

Thanks for reading,

Comment: The decision of index will be entirely based on number of rows a table have and many more..- check a [stackoverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231125/should-i-index-a-bit-field-in-sql-server)

Comment: There is millions of records in some table. The plan asked is about just INCLUDE [Status_ID] in existing Indexes.

Comment: It does depend upon the workload. Adding the bit column wont hurt as it is only a bit. If you want to be sure just create a new index with the additional bit column on 1 or 2 tables and monitor the usage of the index in the system tables. The optimizer might ignore the index as obviously the bit column on its own has a very low cardinality, but combined might push it past over the tipping point.

Comment: yes, But I can see Optimizer picking the existing indexes correctly, but going for a key Loopup just for [Status_ID]. It is not a unique case, I saw a similar behavior in many queries. My question, was that "Will it be sensible, If we just add the Status_ID in the INCLUDE() part of the INDEX"

Comment: Also the frequency when Status_ID is updated should be taken into consideration when thinking about adding it to indexes. If it's rarely updated it shouldn't make a big difference in indexes. But like always, "it depends".

Comment: Great point James, I really did not thought about it.

Comment: i almost conclude that, Forget about Option 1 and use Option 2 for not- frequently updated tables. Hope it will be a good Idea

Comment: What is the distribution of Status_ID? Are there many more 0s than 1s (or vice versa)?

Comment: @ThomasKejser, Status_ID is a bit column.

Comment: @JithinShaji: I understand that, but what is the distribution of them 0/1 values? Are they 50/50 or more skewed?

Comment: I think, there are more number of Ones, when compared to Zeros